# Undefined control sequence. \begin{lstlisting} when using custom cls file

Tags: listings

when I compile this document in texstudio using xelatex:

```
\documentclass{dolphinbook}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=4]{hyperref}

\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    ddddd
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

shows error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \begin{lstlisting}
```

this is the `dolphinbook` class file looks like:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{dolphinbook}
\LoadClass[8pt]{book}

\RequirePackage{listings}

\lstset{      
    alsolanguage= XML,  
    tabsize=4, %  
    frame=shadowbox,   
    commentstyle=\color{red!50!green!50!blue!50},
    frameround=tttt,  
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20}, 
    keywordstyle=\color{blue!90}\bfseries,   
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\ttfamily, 
    keepspaces=true, %  
    breakindent=22pt, % 
    breaklines=true,
    numbers=left,  
    stepnumber=1,
    %numberstyle=\tiny, 
    numberstyle={\color[RGB]{0,192,192}\tiny},
    numbersep=8pt,   
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,  
    showspaces=false, % 
    escapechar=`,
    flexiblecolumns=true, %  
    breaklines=true,  
    breakautoindent=true,%  
    breakindent=4em, %         
    aboveskip=1em,
    tabsize=4,  
    showstringspaces=false, 
    backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{245,245,244},   
    %backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.91,0.91,0.91}    
    escapeinside={``}{\_},  
    %% added by http://bbs.ctex.org/viewthread.php?tid=53451  
    fontadjust,  
    captionpos=t,  
    framextopmargin=2pt,
    framexbottommargin=2pt,
    abovecaptionskip=-3pt,
    belowcaptionskip=3pt,  
    xleftmargin=1em,
    xrightmargin=1em,  
    texcl=true
}
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't trust short error messages delivered by some LaTeX front-ends. The exact error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\lst@fillcolor ->\color
                        [RGB]{245,245,244}
l.12 \begin{lstlisting}
```

Since you apply colors in your `\lstset` setup, for instance

```
    commentstyle=\color{red!50!green!50!blue!50},
```

you want `xcolor` syntax. So add

```
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
```

to your class file.

While you're at it, remove all the trailing `%` in the argument to `\lstset`: they're unnecessary and there's no reason for having them in some lines and not in others.

And the option `[8pt]` to `book` is completely unknown: indeed

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [8pt].
```

tells you exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

With `\RequirePackage{xcolor}` added into the `dolphinbook.cls` file, I can compile your code successfully.